# users and permissions

Tags: sql, database-design, permissions

I want to give some users certain permissions. Would this be the best way? I don't want to make groups like: admin, moderator, normal and so on. I want to be able to give one user maybe access to make news post and another one create poll, and maybe another delete polls.

I'm thinking tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
`username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE `user_permissions` (
`id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
`user_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`can_post_news` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`can_delete_topics` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
 ........
)
```

And On each page I need to check:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_permissions WHERE user_id = $loggedinuser");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

if ($row['can_delete_topics'] == 1) {
mysql_query("delete from topics....");
}
```

Another question: Could I make a function of the 'check code' so I don't need this ugly code on each page? (I'm not so good with functions yet)

Excuse my English, I'm doing my best

Thanks

Comment: Why would you not want to create groups to assign these roles to?  Once that is setup, then all you have to do is add or remove user ids from the role.

Answer (score 5):

a better way could be (using postgresql sql syntax):

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id      SERIAL, -- autoincrementing int
    ...
)

CREATE TABLE permissions (
    id      SERIAL,
    name    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ...
)

create table users_permissions (
    id_user REFERENCES users(id),
    id_permission REFERENCES permission(id),
    UNIQUE(id_user, id_permission)
)
```

and then check for a row in `users_permissions` table.

for your second question the story is longer. for the code above there is no way, you must check that an user has the right permission to execute a particular function. for what i can remember php (isn't it php, right?) has pear that is a library of useful code. there was also a big repository of classes but i can't remember its name.

**Edit:**

i found the site: http://www.phpclasses.org/ how hard to remember...

Comment: +1 and this permission can be read at start of user session into some class variable, and then you simple check for required permission by checking class property. At least this way faster than executing select each time.